# calculate the determinant being, $c_{i,j}=\frac{1}{a_{i}+b_{j}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

For each $ i \in \{1, \cdots, n \} $ are $ a_{i}, b_{i}, \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $ a_{i} + b_{j} \neq0 $ for all $ i, j \in \{1, \cdots, n \} $. Let $ C = (c_{i, j}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ the matrix defined by $$ (c_{i, j}) = \frac {1} {a_{i} + b_{j}} $$ for all $ i, j \in \{1, \cdots, n \} $. Calculate $ \det (C) $

I do not know how to compress him. I tried to find a pattern in the order determinant $ 2 \times 2,3 \times 3 $ but I think it is not working. There is some determinant property that I am forgetting

Comment: this is a type of [Cauchy Determinant](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Value_of_Cauchy_Determinant) and the proof usually goes by minor expansion and observe an inductive property.

Comment: Thank you for the information.